# Html.Bootstrap() not resolving with FluentBootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, fluentbootstrap

I have installed FluentBootstrap v3.3.5 and Bootstrap v3.3.5 in my project, but this in this View, Html.Bootstrap() gives me a compilation error:

```
@using FluentBootstrap;

<h2>Test</h2>

<div>
    <hr />
    @using (var form = Html.Bootstrap().Form().Begin())
    {
        using (var inputGroup = form.InputGroup().Begin())
        {
            @inputGroup.InputGroupAddon("@")
            @inputGroup.Input().SetPlaceholder("Username")
        }
        <br />
        using (var inputGroup = form.InputGroup().Begin())
        {
            @inputGroup.Input()
            @inputGroup.InputGroupAddon(".00")
        }
        <br />
        using (var inputGroup = form.InputGroup().Begin())
        {
            @inputGroup.InputGroupAddon("$")
            @inputGroup.Input()
            @inputGroup.InputGroupAddon(".00")
        }
    }
</div>
```

I have also included FluentBootrap in the namespace section of the ~/Views/web.config.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can we see the corresponding part of your web.config? Maybe there is something wrong?

Comment: I'll have to setup a new sample project as I have continued on this project without FluentBootstrap, but it is something I would like to use in future projects. Give me a day, and I'll update my question.

Comment: Comment when you update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a necro-post I know but for those who also have this question:

You'll need to install FluentBootstrap.Mvc as well which has the Html helpers for Asp.Net MVC

Comment: lol. thanks. yeah my MVC skills have improved significantly since I posted this question. I never looked at it again, but I tend to agree with what you suggest in your answer.

Comment: Glad to hear it :) Please will you accept the answer. My OCD wont rest otherwise, LOL

Answer (score 0):

If you include 3rd party libraries in your project that contain HTML helpers, you typically have to compile first before Visual Studio will recognize them. Until you compile, intellisense will show this error.

Comment: I have compiled. Cleaned and recompiled as well. Was the first thing I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Unload/reload your project. VS will ask you to install 3rd party librairy after reload.